# Assigning objects to { } in Javascript and Hardhat

Tags: javascript, solidity, hardhat

Consider the following code snippet:

```
let { networkConfig, getNetworkIdFromName } = require('../helper-hardhat-config')
const fs = require('fs')

module.exports = async ({
    getNamedAccounts,
    deployments,
    getChainId
}) => {
const { deploy, get, log } = deployments
const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()
const chainId = await getChainId()
let linkTokenAddress
let vrfCoordinatorAddress

if (chainId == 31337) {
    let linkToken = await get('LinkToken')
    let VRFCoordinatorMock = await get('VRFCoordinatorMock')
    linkTokenAddress = linkToken.address
    vrfCoordinatorAddress = VRFCoordinatorMock.address
    additionalMessage = " --linkaddress " + linkTokenAddress

    ...........
    ...........
```

In Javascript, I understand how objects are assigned to variables. eg `x = {one: 1, two: 2 }` but I don't understand how `const { deploy, get, log } = deployments` in the above code works. Just to experiment with, on the console I entered the following lines `{var1,var2}={one: 1, two: 2 }` but the variable **var1 and var2** came as Undefined. I am just trying to understand how  it is possible, for example, to use the **get** property as a function as in `let linkToken = await get('LinkToken')`

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called object destructuring, check about it here https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-object-destructuring-spread-operator-rest-parameter/

Comment: Thank you Jhonny. This is what I was looking for. I didn't know what it was called!